# Pegar o valor faturado do mês anterior

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Boa noite pessoal. Sou estudante iniciante em banco de dados e gostaria de tirar uma dúvida para fins de estudo.

Suponhamos que eu tenha a seguinte estrutura:

```
MES           QTDUSUARIOS       MUNICIPIO       VALORFATURADO

2018-01       136               SERRA           2000
2018-01       108               CAMBURI         1000
2018-02       500               SERRA           1000
2018-02       400               CAMBURI         1500
2018-03       200               SERRA           500
2018-03       120               CAMBURI         500
```

E queira criar uma nova coluna contendo o valor faturado no mês anterior, exemplo:

```
MES           QTDUSUARIOS       MUNICIPIO       VALORFATURADO  VALOR_MES_ANTERIOR

2018-02       500               SERRA           1000           2000
2018-02       400               CAMBURI         1500           1000
2018-03       200               SERRA           500            1000
2018-03       120               CAMBURI         500            1500
```

Como eu faria?
Atualmente, eu realizo a consulta dessa forma:

```
SELECT      TO_CHAR(DATA, 'YYYY-MM') AS MES, 
            SUM(QTDUSUARIOS) AS QTDUSUARIOS, 
            MUNICIPIO, 
            SUM(VALORFATURADO) AS VALORFATURADO 
FROM        UBER 
GROUP BY    TO_CHAR(DATA, 'YYYY-MM'),
            MUNICIPIO 
ORDER BY    1;
```

Script de criação da tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE    UBER (
                ID NUMBER, 
                DATA DATE, 
                QTDUSUARIOS NUMBER(6),
                MUNICIPIO VARCHAR2(50),
                VALORFATURADO NUMBER(8,2) 
)
```

Exemplo de inserção de dados:

```
Insert into UBER (ID,DATA,QTDUSUARIOS,MUNICIPIO,VALORFATURADO) values ('1',to_date('10/01/2018 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'136','SERRA','2000');
```

Comment: Faça um subselect como coluna.

Comment: Boa noite Motta. Você teria exemplos para complementar sua resposta? Links, dicas, qualquer coisa. Obrigado!

Comment: Boa note @Codeman seria muito útil se em vez de simples exemplos você colocasse o script de criação dessa tabela e de inserção dos dados, dessa forma seria muito mais fácil reproduzir o que você tem e te enviar uma resposta mais completa

Comment: Sim, desculpe. Atualizei na descrição da postagem, obrigado pelo aviso!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma solução para o seu problema, é fazer uma coluna com o sub-select, com o `where` e os dados que você precisa.

O SQL completo está em http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/610c68/13

#### Criação da tabela

```
CREATE TABLE    UBER (
                ID NUMBER, 
                DATA DATE, 
                QTDUSUARIOS NUMBER(6),
                MUNICIPIO VARCHAR2(50),
                VALORFATURADO NUMBER(8,2) 
);
```

#### Inserts

```
Insert into UBER (ID,DATA,QTDUSUARIOS,MUNICIPIO,VALORFATURADO) values ('1',to_date('10/01/2018 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'136','SERRA','2000');
Insert into UBER (ID,DATA,QTDUSUARIOS,MUNICIPIO,VALORFATURADO) values ('1',to_date('10/01/2018 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'108','CAMBURI','1000');
Insert into UBER (ID,DATA,QTDUSUARIOS,MUNICIPIO,VALORFATURADO) values ('1',to_date('10/02/2018 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'500','SERRA','1000');
Insert into UBER (ID,DATA,QTDUSUARIOS,MUNICIPIO,VALORFATURADO) values ('1',to_date('10/02/2018 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'400','CAMBURI','1500');
Insert into UBER (ID,DATA,QTDUSUARIOS,MUNICIPIO,VALORFATURADO) values ('1',to_date('10/03/2018 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'200','SERRA','500');
Insert into UBER (ID,DATA,QTDUSUARIOS,MUNICIPIO,VALORFATURADO) values ('1',to_date('10/03/2018 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'400','CAMBURI','500');
```

#### SELECT

```
SELECT      TO_CHAR(DATA, 'YYYY-MM') AS MES, 
            SUM(QTDUSUARIOS) AS QTDUSUARIOS, 
            MUNICIPIO, 
            SUM(VALORFATURADO) AS VALORFATURADO,
            (
                SELECT 
                  SUM(a.VALORFATURADO) 
                FROM 
                  UBER a
                WHERE 
                   TO_CHAR(a.DATA, 'YYYY-MM') = TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(b.DATA, -1), 'YYYY-MM')
                  AND a.MUNICIPIO = b.MUNICIPIO) as VALOR_MES_ANTERIOR
FROM        UBER b
GROUP BY    TO_CHAR(DATA, 'YYYY-MM'),
            MUNICIPIO ,
            TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(DATA, -1), 'YYYY-MM')
ORDER BY    1;
```

## Resultado

```
|     MES | QTDUSUARIOS | MUNICIPIO | VALORFATURADO | VALOR_MES_ANTERIOR |
|---------|-------------|-----------|---------------|--------------------|
| 2018-01 |         108 |   CAMBURI |          1000 |             (null) |
| 2018-01 |         136 |     SERRA |          2000 |             (null) |
| 2018-02 |         400 |   CAMBURI |          1500 |               1000 |
| 2018-02 |         500 |     SERRA |          1000 |               2000 |
| 2018-03 |         400 |   CAMBURI |           500 |               1500 |
| 2018-03 |         200 |     SERRA |           500 |               1000 |
```

Comment: Sensacional, funcionou como uma luva. Grato pelas orientações prestadas Tiedt.

Answer (score 1):

Dessa forma consegue ter o valor faturado do mês anterior mas também a quantidade de usuários e o mês anterior, caso seja necessário:

```
SELECT      U.MUNICIPIO
        ,   U1.MES
        ,   U1.QTDUSUARIOS
        ,   U1.VALORFATURADO
        ,   U2.MES              AS MES_ANTERIOR
        ,   U2.QTDUSUARIOS      AS QTDUSUARIOS_MES_ANTERIOR
        ,   U2.VALORFATURADO    AS VALOR_MES_ANTERIOR
FROM        UBER    U
LEFT JOIN   (
                SELECT      TO_CHAR(DATA, 'YYYY-MM') AS MES
                        ,   SUM(QTDUSUARIOS)    AS QTDUSUARIOS
                        ,   MUNICIPIO
                        ,   SUM(VALORFATURADO)  AS VALORFATURADO 
                FROM        UBER 
                GROUP BY    TO_CHAR(DATA, 'YYYY-MM')
                        ,   MUNICIPIO 
            )       U1 ON U1.M = U.MUNICIPIO
LEFT JOIN   (
                SELECT      TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(DATA, -1), 'YYYY-MM') AS MES
                        ,   SUM(QTDUSUARIOS)    AS QTDUSUARIOS
                        ,   MUNICIPIO
                        ,   SUM(VALORFATURADO)  AS VALORFATURADO 
                FROM        UBER 
                GROUP BY    TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(DATA, -1), 'YYYY-MM')
                        ,   MUNICIPIO 
            )       U2 ON U2.M = U.MUNICIPIO
ORDER BY    U1.MES;
```